# webgl vs. 3rd party plugin (unity3d), best option in browser

Tags: html, 3d, webgl, unity-game-engine

I have been tasked with rendering and manipulating 3d objects in the browser and really want a robust application.  The research that I've done shows two major options here.  I can use the new webgl tool in html5.  Or I can use a browser plugin such as unity3d (i'm sure there are others and for the point of this question, are equivalent).  (Are there any other options that I'm missing?)  My needs for the application are fairly standard, however, these are the focal points:

(1) The most important part is the resolution of the scene. I want as many polygons/points as I can get. I want, hopefully, 1 million polygons/points, 10 million polygons/points, 50 million polygons/points? What is realistically possible?

(2) The scene will be largely static, I will load my scene and then I just want to navigate around it and explore that way. I don't need constant changes to my scene.

Weighing the pros and cons, I see the downside of webgl as not having IE support (yet).  And using unity inconveniences the user by forcing them to install a plugin (which I view as a huge barrier).  If you take those away, is there any performance difference between the two?  Will one give me more polygons than the other?  I would presume they are the same since they both have direct access to the same hardware on the machine.

Any experience or thoughts on this matter would be greatly appreciated ......

Comment: why the downvote? if you downvote, please comment with reason ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WebGL is perfectly capable of rendering [lots](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQrC5YLKFUY&lc=6TQAtYG5SsfTHY1RfEYuOsDjLLcl5n6eGxQlz_jiiBY&feature=inbox) and [lots](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L1XbYhVsD2Q) of [geometry](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORI1Jdk5e5g) as long as you draw it intelligently. So is Unity. Polygon counts are going to be a pretty moot issue, especially if your scene is static.

What you really want to consider more than rendering speed is factors like tool chains and user accessibility. WebGL has a quickly growing community but not much in the way of mature tools. If you need commercial support maybe Unity would be better. WebGL also lacks IE support as you pointed out, but even on browsers that support it you may not be able to access it if your video card is [blacklisted](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=1220892). That said, if for whatever reason you are determined to avoid plugins then your choice is already made, isn't it?

WebGL has an undeniable "geeky cool" factor to it, but that may be completely lost on your target audience. It's also worth considering that Unity is going to be fairly gaming centric, which may or may not be a good thing given your needs. WebGL is more general but lower level.

As far as other alternatives, Flash 11 has Stage3D, which I've heard is very capable, and Silverlight has Molehill, which I've heard next to nothing about (sorry!). Obviously both are plugin-centric, but if you're on the fence they're probably worth at least looking at.

Comment: As complement, I'd like to point that the performances you can expect are dependent of your target audience hardware platforms. All these technologies depend on the graphics hardware performances.

Also, you could consider Google Chrome Frame plugin, which seems to allow easy deployment of 'modern' HTML5/webgl developments.

Comment: Toji, thank you for your comments, I just thumbs up'ed your answer.  Do you disagree with my statement that having users download a plugin is a major hindrance?  Do you develop applications that require plugin downloads?

Comment: I don't develop anything against plugins, but that's mostly because I find it amusing and it happens to be part of my job description. Fact is that right now HTML5 is still finding its feet in a lot of small but important ways, and if you're looking at developing anything 3D commercially __right now__ a plugin may be your best bet. Most users don't see it as THAT much of a hassle, and it will be better supported. If you're doing something as a hobby or school assignment, though, then plugin free can be very fun and educational. It's all about the target audience.

Answer (score 2):

Unity will give you more out of the box, even in terms of performance, than WebGL. This is because Unity already has optimizations for drawing large scenes (culling, batching). In WebGL you may need to write much of this by hand at this point (unless there are some solid WebGL libraries I haven't seen) just to get the same performance. Getting compatible models & textures into Unity is also easier compared to WebGL right now (it's about the maturity of the tools).

Regarding the drawback of needing the Plugin, Unity is releasing at some point in the near future a [Flash 11 exporter](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2011/09/01/unity-and-flash-a-sneak-peek/) which will remove the need for the Unity plugin (depending on your scene).

Comment: I'm a fan of Unity, but Unreal Engine is also going to add Flash support to its engine, in the [future](http://www.unrealengine.com/insiderblog/unreal_engine_3_comes_to_flash). How near that future is, I don't know. So is Crytek, with its Crytek engine, but I don't know how far they are from release.

Answer (score 1):

Did you see Burster Plugin? It is open source, it works like unity, but it opens files from Blender - the best 3d editor :) here is website: http://geta3d.com